# iPad Pages app question mark class

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uikit

I am building an app where I want to display instructions in a UIPopoverController-like way, except without dimming the background. An example of this is in the Pages app for iPad (not sure about iPhone Pages), where hitting the question mark in the upper right hand corner brings up a bunch of little boxes with arrows pointing to what they describe. Does anyone knows what class Pages uses to make those UI components, or if they are not part of UIKit, a potential place to find a class that does the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the UIPopoverController effect, however this won't give you the pointer.

To do it in objc do:

```
image.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
image.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
image.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);

image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

For swift you could do this:

```
image.layer.cornerRadius = 5
image.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
image.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0)

image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {
            self.image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)
        });
```

Comment: I would like the pointers, because the boxes are going to be for explaining button functions, and with several adjacent buttons, it would get confusing. Thanks for the ideas and code though!